# Hovering on div changes the alignment of the text in it

Tags: html, css

What I want is, when i hover on div the image should get visible.
Here is my html and its style

```css
.icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

.text:hover .icon {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  sometext
  <img class="icon" title="Open" src="somepath"></img>
</div>
```

The problem is that when the hover is done, the text shown in div is not center aligned. The text moves up with respect to image.

Comment: Remove the float: right - which is only set when hovering or move it to the .icon class. The image alignement may be to blame and you may want to wrap it up into a wrapping div and use some absolute positioning for the image in a visible div which is absolutely positioned and always visible (so it consumes the space the image will hold when it is visible)

Answer (score 0):

Change your css to:

```
.text:hover .icon
{
  display:inline;
  right:0px;
  position:absolute;
}
```